# style.css update does not working for some codes

Tags: html, css

I want to update style.css of mywebsite , it is working on most of the part but there is specific issue with search icon. I put related photos to attachment highlated with yellow as you may see I can do it on browser but when I change it on style.css it is not working, coming as older. By the way I changed search box by style.css without any issue. Style.css code are below.

Could you please help on this, is there anything that I miss.

```
form.search-form [type="submit"] {
       border: none;
       cursor: pointer;
       padding: 0 16px;
       line-height: 38px;
       height: 65px;
       vertical-align: middle;
       position: absolute; 
       top: 0;
       right: 0;
 }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Try search-form[submit]{
}

You have remember the specificity. To overwrite items with bigger specificity, do you have use !important.

Answer (score 0):

This mostly occurs when your current css code cannot override the default css code applied on the element by default.

To override the default code, you can simply use !important and add it in front of the css code you want to use.

```css
form.search-form [type="submit"] {
       border: none;
       cursor: pointer;
       padding: 0 16px;
       line-height: 38px;
       height: 65px !important;
       vertical-align: middle;
       position: absolute; 
       top: 0;
       right: 0;
 }
```